# Python Google Calendar API trouble

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, bulk, asp.net-web-api

I am able to add multiple events to Google Calendar in bulk, but this is only in my default calendar. How would I be able to get the same code to work with another calendar that I have the URL for?

```
request_feed = gdata.calendar.CalendarEventFeed()

# add events to the request_feed
request_feed.AddInsert(entry=InsertSingleEvent(calendar_service, "walk the dog at 4:00pm"))
request_feed.AddInsert(entry=InsertSingleEvent(calendar_service, "walk the cat at 5:00pm"))

response_feed = calendar_service.ExecuteBatch(request_feed,
gdata.calendar.service.DEFAULT_BATCH_URL))
```

This will work fine and all the events will appear in my calendar right after. But when I replace:

```
response_feed = calendar_service.ExecuteBatch(request_feed,
gdata.calendar.service.DEFAULT_BATCH_URL))
```

With:

```
url = 'calendar/feeds/.../private/full'
response_feed = calendar_service.ExecuteBatch(request_feed,
url))
```

I get errors:

```
gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

Also please note that I have been able to use that URL to add events by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/calendar/service.py), it seems that:

```
DEFAULT_BATCH_URL = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/batch'
```

In your code, it looks like it is trying to resolve a partial URL. If you format the URL as:

```
url = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/.../private/full/batch'
```

It should work.

Comment: THis was almost the full solution. I also had to add /batch to the end of the url

Comment: Ah, gotcha - I'll append the solution for future reference. Glad it worked.